# get_post_meta() unserialize issue - returns boolean(false)

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I'm using a simple custom plugin that parses and saves external XML data as a serialized array in a custom field. This works fine, however, when I update the post, instead of the array I only see a message saying: "bool(false)". I guess it has to with serialize / unserialize but didn't find any clues.

I needed to serialize when I update post meta using `update_post_meta($post_id, 'tb_data', serialize($new_value_array));` By omitting serialize like `update_post_meta($post_id, 'tb_data', $new_value_array);` doesn't store any data in custom field. Furthermore, I have to use `maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tb_data', true));` to print the results.

There are 2 custom fields, (1) tb_item_group_id and (2) tb_data. Value of tb_data will be added using the below function,

Function I am using to update post meta is as below.

```
function parse_file_func($title) {
    // get_tickets_array();exit;
    $language = explode('-', get_bloginfo('language'));
    $language = $language[0];
    $file = file_get_contents('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12344450/feed.xml');
    if (!$file) {
        exit;
    }
    $domObj = new xmlToArrayParser($file);
    $domArr = $domObj->array;
    if (($domObj->parse_error)) {
        echo $domObj->get_xml_error();
    } else {
        $first = $domArr['rss']['channel']['item'];
        foreach ($first as $item) {
            if ($item['languageCode'] == $language) {
                $args = array(
                    'meta_key' => 'tb_item_group_id',
                    'meta_value' => $item['g:item_group_id'],
                    'post_type' => 'tickets',
                );
                $post = get_posts($args);
                if (empty($post)) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    $args = array(
                        'meta_key' => 'tb_item_group_id',
                        'meta_value' => $item['g:item_group_id'],
                        'post_type' => 'tickets',
                    );
                    $post = get_posts($args);
                    $post_id = $post[0]->ID;
                    $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, 'tb_data');
                    if (empty($meta_values)) {
                        $new_value_array = array();
                        unset($item['cdata']);
                        $new_value_array['tb_' . $item['g:item_group_id'] . '_' . $item['ticketID']] = $item;
                    }
                    else {
                        $meta_arrays = unserialize($meta_values[0]);
                        $new_value_array = $meta_arrays;
                        foreach ($meta_arrays as $meta_ticketbar => $tb_content) {
                            if ($meta_ticketbar == 'tb_' . $item['g:item_group_id'] . '_' . $item['ticketID']) {
                                unset($item['cdata']);
                                $new_value_array[$meta_ticketbar] = $item;
                            } else {
                                $new_value_array = $meta_arrays;
                                unset($item['cdata']);
                                $new_value_array['tb_' . $item['g:item_group_id'] . '_' . $item['ticketID']] = $item;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    update_post_meta($post_id, 'tb_data', serialize($new_value_array));
                    // update_post_meta($post_id, 'tb_data', base64_encode($new_value_array));
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and displaying on front-end using `get_post_meta`

```
<?php
    // $tb_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tb_data', true);
    $tb_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tb_data', true);
    $tb_meta_unserialized = maybe_unserialize( $tb_meta );
?>
<pre><?php
    // print_r ($tb_meta_unserialized);
    var_dump($tb_meta_unserialized);
?></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to fix it at my own.

I have used following code to update post meta

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'tb_data', base64_encode(serialize($new_value_array)));
```

...and following code to get post meta

```
$tb_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tb_data', true);
$tb_meta_unserialized = unserialize(base64_decode($tb_meta));
```

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need `base64_encode`/`base64_dencode` for doing PHP serialization/unserialization.

If the metadata contains a serialized array, it will be automatically processed by `unserialize` function. So, to get unserialized data you do not need to use `unserialize` nor `maybe_unserialize` function on received data when using `get_post_meta`.

Also, there is no need for using `serialize` when using `add_post_meta` or `update_post_meta`; if we pass something other than a primitive and non-structural data type like an array or an object, then that will be detected and serialized. So, we only useed to serialize the data when we want to explicit serialize primitive data types like strings, integers, etc.